# Where could I ask about alcohol consumption in public in New Jersey?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which site would this question be appropriate on?

> Can I bring alcohol and consume alcohol at a party in a public park in New Jersey?

Comment: Try searching Google for "[park name] alcohol consumption". e.g. https://www.google.co.uk/#q=new+jersey+Liberty+State+Park+alcohol+consumption leads me to http://www.libertystatepark.org/ which states "*Alcoholic beverages of any sort are forbidden.*"

Comment: From what I recall from my youth, it's going to matter very much if it's a state, county, or town park.

Comment: I, too, am interested in public places where I may consume alcohol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)**

This fits the format for Law perfectly. I know that concerns have been raised  about this question being along the lines of legal advice, which is off-topic for Law. I disagree. Specifically, see [this Law Meta answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222/120) that describes our legal advice policy in detail. While this question uses the personal pronoun "I", it does not fit any of the other criteria for being legal advice.

In fact, the question posed here is of very similar presentation to [Am I allowed to kill a person threatening me? CA, USA](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/am-i-allowed-to-kill-a-person-threatening-me-ca-usa), which got a very good reception. The common phrasing is basically

> Can I do X in jurisdiction Y?

. . . which is okay as a general question. If this question went into specifics, then there would be a problem.

[This Law Meta discussion](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227/what-criteria-distinguish-a-hypothetical-from-legal-advice) is also important. There is not enough information in the question presented to give accurate legal advice. Some may nitpick me on that, but this question is fine by our policy.

Comment: I tried posting the question, but I couldn't and it said "This post doesn't meet our quality standards. I don't know why. :( I still would like to post the question, if it would let me.

Comment: @jo99blackops What did you put in the question body? Making it too short can cause that message to appear.

Comment: The body was: "Does NJ law prohibit alcohol consumption in public parks? Thanks!" I think its pretty dumb to not be able to post a question when a few words is enough. How many characters does it have to be?

Comment: @jo99blackops Yep, you'll need to make it longer. That's the only problem with it.

Answer (score 4):

That would be a legal question at first, which isn't a really good one for SE since most of us aren't lawyers. That would make the question not fit for most sites here.

I have seen such questions on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com), but those were often not quite legal based, but more 'could I do this or that in India' like questions in the sense of cultural acceptance.

Please don't use that site as a 'last resort'. Make sure to read their help center to see [what is on-topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

**Probably a legal person or a town clerk is what you need.**

Comment: I was thinking maybe the "Law" site?

Comment: No. I am quite certain they won't accept such question, since that site is for legal experts, not for anyone looking for legal advice.

Comment: I'll read the Travel.SE help center stuff.

Comment: @Pat Maybe law would work here because it's a basic and fixed law which can be looked up - i.e. it doesn't depend on a specific scenario or parameters etc

Comment: It's not a basic law @James; the OP would need to specify the exact park they intend to go to...

Comment: @james from law.se: *Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter.*

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Which is perfectly fine "Can I legally drink alcohol in XYZ Park?" which is a *fixed* law (in fact Google would probably answer this). Not like "Will my wife get 50% in our divorce")

Comment: @pat the full quote is "*Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are off-topic for Law Stack Exchange. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.*" You do not need to be a lawyer to look up government laws as to whether drinking in a specific public place is legal or not. It's a fixed law not requiring legal training. That said, I've not used the site so go by others' better judgements. And again, Google will probs answer this.

Comment: It's just worded poorly, "can I..." could be changed to "does NJ law prohibit alcohol consumption in public parks?" Making it a question about laws, not about the particular person's situation.

Comment: Fair enough all. Wasn't arguing, just seems to me to be "answerable". Have suggested to OP in comment they search Google. Found info pretty easily for one park as an example

Comment: When I try to ask the question on Travel.SE, it says that the question does not meet their quality standards.

Comment: @jo99blackops Why use "travel" site to ask about a drinking law in a park? It's unlikely it will be welcomed there. See my comment on your question :)

Comment: @James I tried that for my park, didn't work :( Brought the address and stuff on the township page, but no rules.

Comment: I'm going to contact the township about this. Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, this kind of thing is fine for Law. Just change the wording a little. Also, it's not directly asking for legal advice in the same way as "Can I sue my neighbor if he runs over my unicorn?" is.

Comment: Rather, the unacceptable example should be "*Should* I sue my neighbor if he runs over my unicorn?" My bad there. I should add that Travel is still a good suggestion, though - just perhaps not necessarily the best.